# How to use TimerTask in Jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, timertask

Hi, I am trying to access an array list using `TimerTask`. I want to get array list value in different 2 sub-lists and then want to print that all lists on jsp page between 5 second time interval

Here is my Code :

**ScheduledTask**

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
 public void run() {

    }
}
```

**My.jsp**

```
 <%@ page import="Demo.ScheduledTask"%>
<html>
<head>

    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <jsp:useBean id="test" class="Demo.ScheduledTask" />
  <%

  Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(st, 0, 1000);
                    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
            URL url;
        try {
            // get URL content

            String a = "http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
            url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
           List sublist1=null;
           List sublist2=null;
           List sublist3=null;
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

                s = s.replace("~", " ");
                //System.out.println(s);
                StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();
                    String price = str.nextElement().toString();
                    list1.add(mandi);
                    list2.add(price);

                }
            } sublist1=list1.subList(0, 15);
            sublist2=list1.subList(16,30);
             sublist3=list1.subList(31,45);
            String item1 = null;
            for (int l = 0; l < sublist1.size(); l++) 

            {
               out.println("List1"+sublist1.get(l));
            } 
            Thread.sleep(5000);
                for(int j=0;j<sublist2.size();j++)
                {
                   out.println("List2"+sublist2.get(j));

                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                for(int k=0;k<sublist2.size();k++){
                   out.println("List3"+sublist3.get(k));
            }
            Thread.sleep(5000);
           if (i == 2) 
            {
                out.println("Application Terminates");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            br.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


        }
  %>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve my desired output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307964/countdown-timer-in-jsp-servlets check this

Answer (score 1):

Guess you want the user to see new content every 5 secons right? You cannot do this in a JSP, since the JSP is generating the html page which is sent to the browser. It's not executed in the browser.

You can

- Rewrite your timed action in JavaScript. This would be executed in the broswer.
- Set-up an ajax call back in JavaScript which gets called periodically to execute what you have inside your timer task and sent the result to the browser to update the UI.

Comment: You need to use [Java Script Timing Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval)